# Codeigniter update values in a table

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I'm learning to use codeigniter with rest_controller library.

I'm searching to update some values in a table in my db.

I have in my controller:

```
public function guest_patch(){
        $idperson = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $person = array(
            'fiscalcode' => $this->input->post('fiscalcode'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'surname' => $this->input->post('surname')
        );
        $this->load->model('Person_model');
        $data = $this->Person_model->patch($idperson, $person);
        $this->response($data);
    }
```

while in my model:

```
public function patch($idperson, $person){
        $this->fiscalcode = $person['fiscalcode'];
        $this->name = $person['name'];
        $this->surname = $person['surname'];
        $result = $this->db->update('Persons', $this, array('id' => $idperson));
        if($result){
            return("Dati aggiornati");
        }
    }
```

I have two question for you:

1) In this case when I launch the **update** method the values in my db are deleted (or substitute by 0). Infact I have tried to print $person in my model and all the values that I passed (using postman) are empty. While if I insert the data manually in the controller like:

```
'fiscalcode' =>'NewFiscalCode'
```

the data in db are updated.
How can I do to update values that I recover from a form-data (at the moment that I pass using postman)?

2) If I don't want to update a value and so I leave a field empty ( for example I wrote in the form-data only the name and surname but I don't want to change the fiscalcode field), the data in the db about this field "fiscalcode" will be eliminated?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:**

I guess u gave column *'fiscalcode'* as integer in DB and you are trying to update non int data. So *MySQL* is reseting field as 0;

**Case 2:**

Update *Controller* code as like this:

```
$person = array(            
    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
    'surname' => $this->input->post('surname')
);

if($this->input->post('fiscalcode')){
   $person['fiscalcode'] = $this->input->post('fiscalcode');
}
```

Update *Model* code as like this:

```
if(isset($person['fiscalcode'])){
    $this->fiscalcode = $person['fiscalcode'];
}
```

It will assign only when you post data with parameter 'fiscalcode'

Comment: Nobody of these values are int. The problem in my opinion is in the controller. I have tried to var_dump the object $person and the result is: `array (size=3)
  'fiscalcode' => null
  'name' => null
  'surname' => null`

Comment: @Jack i was trying to say that your table column might be defined as "integer not null column" ...so if you are trying to insert a non integer value like 'null' it will reset its value to 0.

Comment: Ok but I'm trying to insert some values using postman (form-data). I have tried for example to pass only name: NewName and surname: NewSurname. But the var_dump in the post give me null for these values

Answer (score 1):

```
//use route for this in inside config/routes.php
$route['edit/(:any)'] = 'controller_name/guest_patch/$1';

public function guest_patch($idperson){
  $person = array(
            'fiscalcode' => $this->input->post('fiscalcode'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'surname' => $this->input->post('surname')
     );
  $this->load->model('Person_model');
  $data = $this->Person_model->patch($idperson, $person);
  $this->response($data);
    }
//model
public function patch($idperson, $person){
        return $this->db->where('idperson',$idperson)->update($person);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggest me, but the result doesn't change. The problem in my opinion is in the controller. I have tried to var_dump the object $person and the result is: `array (size=3)
  'fiscalcode' => null
  'name' => null
  'surname' => null`